# Authentication with search-tweets-ruby (premium API)

Tags: ruby, twitter

This question is about the [search-tweets-ruby](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-ruby) client provided by twitter for use with their premium and enterprise API's.

I am following the instructions and run into a 'Bad Authentication data' error when running the app (via terminal - Mac OS X) to retrieve tweets with a single rule.

The 'bearer token' and 'dev environment' are correct because a Curl request works.

The following are the contents of my ./config/config.yaml file

```
auth:
  app_token: my_generated_bearer_token

labels:
  environment: my_dev_environment_name

options:
  search_type: premium
  archive: fullarchive
  max_results: 500
  write_mode: standard-out
  out_box: ./output
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but would appreciate an assist. I haven't worked with the Twitter API before, although I've reviewed the documentation before asking on SO.

Thanks, everyone.

Update:

The first sample call, from the provided link is:

```
$ruby ./search-app.rb -r "snow profile_region:colorado has:media".
```

This yields a 'bad authentication error'.
I provided the contents of my yaml file, because presumably that is the only difference between the Curl request and the client app, if the 'bearer token' and 'environment name' work with Curl.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/prod.json \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMLheAAAAAAA0%2BuSeid%2BULvsea4JtiGRiSDSJSI%3DEUifiRBkKG5E2XzMDjRfl76ZC9Ub0wnz4XsNiRVBChTYbJcE3F' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
                "query":"from:TwitterDev lang:en",
                "maxResults": "100",
                "fromDate":"201811010000", 
                "toDate":"201811062359"
                }'
```

There is no code.

Comment: As this is a private API that we cannot access it is imperative that you are very specific with the details you provide. Statements like "I am following the instructions" and "a Curl request works" are not diagnostically useful: the README is ten pages long and you have not provided your actual cURL request. Likewise, you have provided no code here at all. How can anyone tell you what's wrong with your code if we can't see any code?

Comment: The first sample call, from the provided link is:
$ruby ./search-app.rb -r "snow profile_region:colorado has:media". <--This yields a 'bad authentication error' 
I provided the contents of my yaml file, because presumably that is the only difference between the Curl request and the client app, if the bearer token and environment name work with Curl. 
curl -X POST "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/:product/:label.json" -d '{"query":"TwitterDev "search api"","maxResults":"500","fromDate":"<yyyymmddhhmm>","toDate":"<yyyymmddhhmm>"}' -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" 
There is no code.

Comment: I can't read any of this because you've placed it in a comment. Please place relevant information in your post.

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: Is the error exactly that: "Bad authentication"? I can't seem to reproduce this, if I enter an invalid token I get "Invalid or expired token" as the error message. One thing to note is that the sample call there will only work as posted, if you have a paid premium subscription - the profile_region search operator is not available in the free sandbox, and you can only search for up to 100 results in the sandbox tier, not 500.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Andy. I tried searching for a simple string, and the exact response was:

{"error":{"message":"Bad Authentication data.","sent":"2020-05-02T02:42:09+00:00","transactionId":"005e3bef000d30e7"}}

I have since managed to use curl requests to the full archive endpoint, to retrieve the data.  Was there anything wrong with my Yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your YAML file is configured for the full-archive search endpoint, yet your CURL-based call is going to the 30-day search endpoint. If you update the YAML file to point to the '30day' endpoint, I suspect it will succeed.